# Assign a non-sequential index to items in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Is there a way of programmatically assigning an index to an item in a ComboBox, as I add the items, rather than using the default sequential 0-based index?

e.g. consider the HTML equivalent, the `<select>` box...

```
<select name="test">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="324">Sixteen Score and Four</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to simulate the "value" attribute in a combo box in c#.

I know the alternative is to set up another array which maps the default Index to "my" index, but this seems somewhat inelegant, seeing as this will have to be accessed in numerous places...

Answer (score 3):

You can define a simple class that has a `Value` property and a `Text` property (for example), and add items of that type (rather than strings) to the `ComboBox`.  Just make sure the class's `ToString` method returns what you want displayed in the `ComboBox`.